# Jest: How to unmock components listed in an index.js file?

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Using Jest to unit test my react components.

I list my components under `src/components/index.js` so I can to do the following:

`import { MyComponent } from 'components';`

When using jest how do I call `unmock` on such a require path?

```
jest.unmock('components/MyComponent'); // ???

import { MyComponent } from 'components';

// ... tests below ...
```

The above does not work, although that is basically the desired outcome.

Comment: Tried using `unmockedModulePathPatterns`?

Comment: yep. no luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issues previously and removing the import destructuring works with jest 12.0.1.

So rather than;

```
import { MyComponent } from 'components';
```

Try;

```
import index from 'components'
// test code
index.MyComponent
```

Personally I normally just directly include the component I want under test rather than referencing it from the index. Using the index only seems worth while when using a test library that doesn't define a standard of having your tests next to the code.